# Windows10: how to change IPv4/IPv6 settings when using VPN

Tags: networking, windows-10

On a new PC with Windows10 preinstalled I wanted to change some network settings, in particular this one:

[image]

While trying this I discovered a strange issue: I can not click on the properties button. It seems to be some sort of deactivated.

[image]

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Huh? What actually happens when you click it? It doesn't seem deactivated at all in your screenshot?

Comment: there's slightly a change in background color and border thickness when hovering or clicking but nothing else happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Powershell to  enable/disable the "Use default gateway on remote network" option:

```
Get-VpnConnection
Set-VpnConnection -Name "myVPN" -SplitTunneling $True
```

Comment: I tried to split the tunneling as you wrote. Now "SplitTunneling" is listed as "true" but still ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when using VPN :-(

Comment: You get this error on the webbrowser i suppose? Did you try rebuilding the VPN connection after applying the powershell cmd? Also try it with a different browser.

Comment: You are right. I tried to open adresses in the browser directly after changing the option for SplitTunneling. Today it works, but the "properties" button for IPv4 (and IPv6 too) still doesn't work. There are two other buttons in the dialog box of which the first one ("install") is clickable. Seems to be a bug I suppose.